# ubuntu different scale for different monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

i have two different resolution monitors(3840x2160 and 1920x1080), but same size(all 27 in)。
3840x2160 is too small, i have try xrandr (--scale 0.5x0.5) and change Scale in Settings(Devices-Displays-Scale), but they all have problem。
- xrandr will make 3840x2160 monitors blurry
- Settings will make 1920x1080 monitors too big, and can't set different scale for different monitors.

some infomation:
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
GNOME 3.28.2
monitors(3840x2160 and 1920x1080)

Comment: find a solution:
1. scale 1920x1080 monitor :`--output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0 --rotate right --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal`
2. change all monitor's scale by GNOME Setting

Comment: sorry how to do this?